# How can I make half the player come out on the other side?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, draw, bounds

Here's my code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

var w = canvas.width
var h = canvas.height

var player = {
x: w / 2,
y: h / 2,
r: 10,
vx: 0,
vy: 0,
speed: 5,
}

var keys = []


window.onkeydown = function(event) {keys[event.keyCode] = true}
window.onkeyup = function(event) {keys[event.keyCode] = false}

setInterval(update, 1000 / 60)
function update() {
if (keys[38] && player.vy > -player.speed) {
    player.vy--
}
if (keys[40] && player.vy < player.speed) {
    player.vy++
}
if (keys[37] && player.vx > -player.speed) {
    player.vx--
}
if (keys[39] && player.vx < player.speed) {
    player.vx++
}

player.vx *= 0.9
player.vy *= 0.9
player.x += player.vx
player.y += player.vy

ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h)
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.arc(player.x, player.y, player.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
ctx.fillStyle = "red"
ctx.fill()
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wfNse/

So, my question is, how can I make the player come out on the other side when you go out side of the bounds? Now this is pretty easily done, so there's one more thing, when half the player is out of the bounds, I want it to be seen half on both sides, like this:

[image: (Made with paint)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :

```
// coordinates replaced in the board
player.x = (player.x+w)%w;
player.y = (player.y+h)%h;

// player position drawing
ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h)
ctx.beginPath()
for (var i=-1; i<=1; i++) {
    for (var j=-1; j<=1; j++) {
        var x = player.x+i*w, y = player.y+j*h;
        if (x+player.r<0 || x-player.r>w || y+player.r<0 || y-player.r>h) continue;
        ctx.arc(x, y, player.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)    
    }
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/rycAV/)

Comment: There's one problem, go upwards and pass the up-bound two times, and the player will vanish...

Comment: Sorry, but I found one more thing, The players x can be out bounds and that causes trouble in my real code

Comment: The x should fit in with the drawings

Comment: I mean that the x sometimes is somewhere else than the drawed red dot: http://jsfiddle.net/xcdM6/

Comment: Don't use alerts like that, use [console.log](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console). But isn't my new version what you look for ?

Comment: I give you an upvote and accept your answer, thanks dude you helped me alot.

Comment: The new version was exactly what I was I looking for.

Comment: Well, I found one more glitch, if the players X is zero and the players Y is zero, the player isn't being drawed at all the four corners, only at three of them... Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Thanks it works fine, and I have already declared 0 bugs/glitches.